# parallel parLapply setup

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to use part of speech tagging from the openNLP/NLP packages in parallel.  I need the code to work on any OS so am opting to use the `parLapply` function from parallel (but am open to other OS independent options).  In the past I ran `tagPOS` function from the openNLP package in `parLapply` with no problem.  However, the openNLP package had some recent changes that eliminated `tagPOS` and added some more flexible options.  Kurt was kind enough to help me recreate the `tagPOS` function from the new package's tools.  I can get the `lapply` version to work but not the parallel version.  It keeps saying the nodes need more variables passed to them until it finally asks for a non-exported function from openNLP.  This seems odd it would keep asking for more and more variables to be passed which tells me I'm setting up the `parLapply` incorrectly.  How can I set up the `tagPOS` to operate in an parallel, OS independent fashion?

```
library(openNLP)
library(NLP)
library(parallel)

## POS tagger
tagPOS <-  function(x, pos_tag_annotator, ...) {
    s <- as.String(x)
    ## Need sentence and word token annotations.
    word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
    a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
    a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
    a3 <- annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)

    ## Determine the distribution of POS tags for word tokens.
    a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
    POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))

    ## Extract token/POS pairs (all of them): easy.
    POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
    list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
} ## End of tagPOS function 

## Set up a parallel run
text.var <- c("I like it.", "This is outstanding soup!",  
    "I really must get the recipe.")
ntv <- length(text.var)
PTA <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()   

cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()/2))
clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("text.var", "ntv", 
    "tagPOS", "PTA", "as.String", "Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator"), 
    envir = environment())
m <- parLapply(cl, seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
        x <- tagPOS(text.var[i], PTA)
        return(x)
    }
)
stopCluster(cl)

## Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
##   3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function 
##   "Maxent_Simple_Word_Tokenizer"

openNLP::Maxent_Simple_Word_Tokenizer

## >openNLP::Maxent_Simple_Word_Tokenizer
## Error: 'Maxent_Simple_Word_Tokenizer' is not an exported 
##     object from 'namespace:openNLP'

## It's a non exported function
openNLP:::Maxent_Simple_Word_Tokenizer


## Demo that it works with lapply
lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
    tagPOS(text.var[i], PTA)
})

lapply(text.var, function(x) {
    tagPOS(x, PTA)
})

## >     lapply(seq_len(ntv), function(i) {
## +         tagPOS(text.var[i], PTA)
## +     })
## [[1]]
## [[1]]$POStagged
## [1] "I/PRP like/IN it/PRP ./."
## 
## [[1]]$POStags
## [1] "PRP" "IN"  "PRP" "."  
## 
## [[1]]$word.count
## [1] 3
## 
## 
## [[2]]
## [[2]]$POStagged
## [1] "THis/DT is/VBZ outstanding/JJ soup/NN !/."
## 
## [[2]]$POStags
## [1] "DT"  "VBZ" "JJ"  "NN"  "."  
## 
## [[2]]$word.count
## [1] 4
## 
## 
## [[3]]
## [[3]]$POStagged
## [1] "I/PRP really/RB must/MD get/VB the/DT recip/NN ./."
## 
## [[3]]$POStags
## [1] "PRP" "RB"  "MD"  "VB"  "DT"  "NN"  "."  
## 
## [[3]]$word.count
## [1] 6
```

**EDIT: per Steve's suggestion**

Note the openNLP is brand new.  I installed ver 2.1 from a tar.gz from CRAN.  I get the following error even though this function exists.

```
library(openNLP); library(NLP); library(parallel)

tagPOS <-  function(text.var, pos_tag_annotator, ...) {
    s <- as.String(text.var)

    ## Set up the POS annotator if missing (for parallel)
    if (missing(pos_tag_annotator)) {
        PTA <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
    }

    ## Need sentence and word token annotations.
    word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
    a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
    a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
    a3 <- annotate(s, PTA, a2)

    ## Determine the distribution of POS tags for word tokens.
    a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
    POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, "[[", "POS"))

    ## Extract token/POS pairs (all of them): easy.
    POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
    list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}

text.var <- c("I like it.", "This is outstanding soup!",  
    "I really must get the recipe.")

cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()/2))
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(openNLP); library(NLP)})
m <- parLapply(cl, text.var, tagPOS)

## > m <- parLapply(cl, text.var, tagPOS)
## Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
##   3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator"

stopCluster(cl)


> packageDescription('openNLP')
Package: openNLP
Encoding: UTF-8
Version: 0.2-1
Title: Apache OpenNLP Tools Interface
Authors@R: person("Kurt", "Hornik", role = c("aut", "cre"), email =
          "Kurt.Hornik@R-project.org")
Description: An interface to the Apache OpenNLP tools (version 1.5.3).  The Apache OpenNLP
          library is a machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language
          text written in Java.  It supports the most common NLP tasks, such as tokenization,
          sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking,
          parsing, and coreference resolution.  See http://opennlp.apache.org/ for more
          information.
Imports: NLP (>= 0.1-0), openNLPdata (>= 1.5.3-1), rJava (>= 0.6-3)
SystemRequirements: Java (>= 5.0)
License: GPL-3
Packaged: 2013-08-20 13:23:54 UTC; hornik
Author: Kurt Hornik [aut, cre]
Maintainer: Kurt Hornik <Kurt.Hornik@R-project.org>
NeedsCompilation: no
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2013-08-20 15:41:22
Built: R 3.0.1; ; 2013-08-20 13:48:47 UTC; windows
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're calling functions from `NLP` on the cluster workers, you should load it on each of the workers before calling `parLapply`.  You can do that from the worker function, but I tend to use `clusterCall` or `clusterEvalQ` right after creating the cluster object:

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(openNLP); library(NLP)})
```

Since `as.String` and `Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator` are in those packages, they shouldn't be exported.

Note that while running your example on my machine, I noticed that the `PTA` object doesn't work after being exported to the worker machines.  Presumably there is something in that object that can't be safely serialized and unserialized.  After I created that object on the workers using `clusterEvalQ`, the example ran successfully.  Here it is, using openNLP 0.2-1:

```
library(parallel)
tagPOS <-  function(x, ...) {
    s <- as.String(x)
    word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
    a2 <- Annotation(1L, "sentence", 1L, nchar(s))
    a2 <- annotate(s, word_token_annotator, a2)
    a3 <- annotate(s, PTA, a2)
    a3w <- a3[a3$type == "word"]
    POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
    POStagged <- paste(sprintf("%s/%s", s[a3w], POStags), collapse = " ")
    list(POStagged = POStagged, POStags = POStags)
}
text.var <- c("I like it.", "This is outstanding soup!",
    "I really must get the recipe.")
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", detectCores()/2))
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(openNLP)
    library(NLP)
    PTA <- Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
})
m <- parLapply(cl, text.var, tagPOS)
print(m)
stopCluster(cl)
```

If `clusterEvalQ` fails because Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator is not found, you might be loading the wrong version of openNLP on the workers.  You can determine what package versions you're getting on the workers by executing `sessionInfo` with `clusterEvalQ`:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(openNLP); library(NLP)})
clusterEvalQ(cl, sessionInfo())
```

This will return the results of executing `sessionInfo()` on each of the cluster workers. Here is the version information for some of the packages that I'm using and that work for me:

```
other attached packages:
[1] NLP_0.1-0     openNLP_0.2-1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] openNLPdata_1.5.3-1 rJava_0.9-4
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.  The same error persists though.

Comment: @TylerRinker  Does it help if you don't explicitly export Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator?

Comment: Steve Thank you again for your time.  I get the same error.  See my edit above.  Can you try with openNLP 2.1. I cannot try 2.0 as I have no Internet to my computer.  Note the new names for functions in 2.1

Comment: @TylerRinker openNLP 0.2-1 works for me. Are you doing anything special to get that version of openNLP to be used?  Maybe the workers are getting a different version.  See my edited answer for details.

Comment: The problem was I still had `Sys.setenv("R_LIBS_USER" = "C:/R/R-3.0.0/library")` so the new version of openNLP was not found by the clusters.  The suggestions you gave were spot on.

Comment: @TylerRinker That also explains why you were missing non-exported functions originally.  I'm glad it's now working for you.