# Add ID column to R CoreNLP package tokenizer output using lapply

Tags: r, stanford-nlp, lapply, do.call

I have working code to get tokenizer output from CoreNLP using lapply and do.call. I need help to achieve 2 things if possible:

1. Add Document Id in the apply function itself (Currently code doesn't have this column added)
2. Achieve the results of do.call in apply function itself (if possible)

There is this post  [parallel parLapply setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357788/parallel-parlapply-setup) which uses "lapply" function. But it just works on the text vector and doesnot take into account and id column.

**Code:**

```
#Fake data - Quotes from Great Expectations by Charles Dickens
textcolumn<-c("The broken heart. You think you will die, but you just keep living, day after day after terrible day.",
              "We need never be ashamed of our tears.")
DocId <-c(1:length(textcolumn))

options( java.parameters = "-Xmx2g" ) 
library(coreNLP)
#initCoreNLP() # change this if downloaded to non-standard location
initCoreNLP(annotators = "tokenize,ssplit,pos")

# Function to tokenize
tokenize <- function(textcolumn) {
  tmp<-annotateString(textcolumn)
  tokens<-getToken(tmp)
  colnames(tokens)<-tolower(colnames(tokens))
  tokens[,c("sentence", "id", "token" ,"pos")]
}

result <- lapply(textcolumn,tokenize)
final <- do.call(rbind,result)
```

**Output**

```
> final

   sentence id    token  pos
1         1  1      The   DT
2         1  2   broken   JJ
3         1  3    heart   NN
4         1  4        .    .
5         2  1      You  PRP
6         2  2    think  VBP
7         2  3      you  PRP
8         2  4     will   MD
9         2  5      die   VB
10        2  6        ,    ,
11        2  7      but   CC
12        2  8      you  PRP
13        2  9     just   RB
14        2 10     keep  VBP
15        2 11   living   NN
16        2 12        ,    ,
17        2 13      day   NN
18        2 14    after   IN
19        2 15      day   NN
20        2 16    after   IN
21        2 17 terrible   JJ
22        2 18      day   NN
23        2 19        .    .
24        1  1       We  PRP
25        1  2     need  VBP
26        1  3    never   RB
27        1  4       be   VB
28        1  5  ashamed   JJ
29        1  6       of   IN
30        1  7      our PRP$
31        1  8    tears  NNS
32        1  9        .    .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to add the document id to the output of CoreNLP in the tokenizer function. Since lapply doesn't allow 2 arguments i had to switch to mapply. Also i had to convert the output of the function into a list to get proper output.

**Code:**

```
#Fake data - Quotes from Great Expectations by Charles Dickens
textcolumn<-c("The broken heart. You think you will die, but you just keep living, day after day after terrible day.",
              "We need never be ashamed of our tears.")
DocId <-c(1:length(textcolumn))

options( java.parameters = "-Xmx2g" ) 
library(coreNLP)
#initCoreNLP() # change this if downloaded to non-standard location
initCoreNLP(annotators = "tokenize,ssplit,pos")

# Function to tokenize
tokenize <- function(textcolumn,DocId) {
  tmp<-annotateString(textcolumn)
  tokens<-getToken(tmp)
  colnames(tokens)<-tolower(colnames(tokens))
  tokens <- tokens[,c("sentence", "id", "token" ,"pos")] # keeping only few columns
  colnames(tokens) <- c("sentence", "tokenid", "token" ,"pos")
  DocId <- rep(DocId,length(tokens[,1]))
  docidtokens<-cbind(DocId,tokens)
  docidtokens <- list(docidtokens) # need to convert into list for proper output
}

result <- mapply(tokenize, textcolumn, DocId)
final <- do.call(rbind,result)
```

**Output:**

```
> print(final, row.names = FALSE)
 DocId sentence tokenid    token  pos
     1        1       1      The   DT
     1        1       2   broken   JJ
     1        1       3    heart   NN
     1        1       4        .    .
     1        2       1      You  PRP
     1        2       2    think  VBP
     1        2       3      you  PRP
     1        2       4     will   MD
     1        2       5      die   VB
     1        2       6        ,    ,
     1        2       7      but   CC
     1        2       8      you  PRP
     1        2       9     just   RB
     1        2      10     keep  VBP
     1        2      11   living   NN
     1        2      12        ,    ,
     1        2      13      day   NN
     1        2      14    after   IN
     1        2      15      day   NN
     1        2      16    after   IN
     1        2      17 terrible   JJ
     1        2      18      day   NN
     1        2      19        .    .
     2        1       1       We  PRP
     2        1       2     need  VBP
     2        1       3    never   RB
     2        1       4       be   VB
     2        1       5  ashamed   JJ
     2        1       6       of   IN
     2        1       7      our PRP$
     2        1       8    tears  NNS
     2        1       9        .    .
```