# R: Time Series Models in Parallel

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
countries <- c(1, 2)
 
cities <- c("A", "B")   

weeks <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"), by="week"), length(countries)*length(cities))
 
counts <- rpois(length(weeks), lambda = 50)

df <- data.frame(
  Country = rep(countries, each = length(weeks)/(length(countries)*length(cities))),
  City = rep(cities, length(weeks)/(length(countries)*length(cities))),
  Week = as.character(weeks),
  Count = counts
)
```

**I want to fit 4 time series models (auto.arima) to Country1-CityA, Country1-CityB, Country2-CityA and Country2-CityB**

I did this with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)

#Group data by Country and City
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(Country, City)

# Define a function to fit ARIMA model for each group
fit_arima <- function(df) {
  arima_model <- auto.arima(df$Count)
  return(arima_model)
}

# Apply the function to each group using lapply
arima_models <- df_grouped %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(arima_model = lapply(data, fit_arima))

# Extract models for each group
arima_model_a_a <- arima_models$arima_model[[1]]
arima_model_a_b <- arima_models$arima_model[[2]]
arima_model_b_a <- arima_models$arima_model[[3]]
arima_model_b_b <- arima_models$arima_model[[4]]
```

**My Question:** Now, I want to improve the performance of this code using "parallel computing".

I read that there are different options for this task - this includes libraries such as "foreach", "doParallel", "doSNOW", "clustereval" etc.

I tried to adapt some of these methodologies to my problem:

```
# Define the number of cores to use
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1

# Create a cluster 
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

# Bundle all libraries needed
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(forecast)
})


# Use parLapply to fit ARIMA models in parallel
ARIMA_Models <- parLapply(cl, ARIMA_List, function(x) {
  auto.arima(x$Count)
})

# EXIT
stopCluster(cl)
```

The code seems to have run - but **can someone please help me understand if I have done this correctly? Is there a better way to accomplish this?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [Training Multiple Auto.Arima Models in Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539765/training-multiple-auto-arima-models-in-parallel)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/179144/r-parallelising-auto-arima

Answer (score 1):

Since you are nesting already, I recommend skipping the `lapply` and just use `furrr`.

```
countries <- c(1, 2)

cities <- c("A", "B")   

weeks <- rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2023-01-01"), by="week"), length(countries)*length(cities))

counts <- rpois(length(weeks), lambda = 50)

df <- data.frame(
  Country = rep(countries, each = length(weeks)/(length(countries)*length(cities))),
  City = rep(cities, length(weeks)/(length(countries)*length(cities))),
  Week = as.character(weeks),
  Count = counts
)

library(furrr)
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)

#Group data by Country and City
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(Country, City)

# Define a function to fit ARIMA model for each group
fit_arima <- function(df) {
  arima_model <- auto.arima(df$Count)
  return(arima_model)
}

plan(multisession, workers = 10)

arima_models <- df_grouped %>%
  nest() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # Important to do this
  mutate(arima_model = future_map(.x = data, ~fit_arima(.x)))
```

Comment: @ bobloblawlawblog: thank you so much for your answer! what do you think the advantages of this approach is compared to mine? thanks!

Comment: Anytime! I am not an expert in parallel computing, but for me it is a personal choice. I think the code is cleaner, but also, it lets you use other `purrr` functionality seamlessly; for example, error handling on a large (I have done one over 10k) `fit_arima` execution using [possibly](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/possibly.html). I forgot to tell you, once you are done, you can close your workers using `plan(sequential)`. I am learning things as well, and please let me know if you find a better way of doing this :)